# How to Select and Print certain sheets from Excel?

Tags: c#, excel

I am writing a program that print an excel file.
I want to print the active sheets I chose every time.
for example I have an Excel file has 5 sheets .
I want to do this :

1- select the 3 sheets i want ("A" , "B", "C")

2- change their size to A4

3- print them in one file.

here is my code :

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();            

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(filePath,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet aa in wb.Sheets)
            {
                aa.Select(); 
                aa.Activate();
                aa.PageSetup.PaperSize = excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4;
            }

            wb.PrintOutEx(
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();


            wb.Close(false, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(wb);

            excelApp.Quit();
            Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(excelApp);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what, specifically, the problem you're encountering is?

Comment: actually it is difficult to explain but i will try , when i try to print some files it gets separated into two files specially if i am using a PDF printer , so it just print the first sheet alone and the rest of sheets on another PDF file , to solve this i have to manually select all sheets i want , the from Page Setup I change the Size to any size (A4)  then Print the Active sheets , with this method i get what i want , i just want to convert these steps to my code , hope you got it .